# How to get all featured image sizes and their URLs?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

Is there a standard way to get all the registered sizes of the featured images?
One can register different sizes with `add_image_size()`.
What I need, is to get all the sizes of a featured image of a post.
Something like this:

$sizes = get_post_feature_image_sizes($postid);

...which will return an array of objects like this (here in JSON format):

```
[
{width: 200, height: 300, url: 'http://.........../wp-content/uploads/2015/10/file-200x300.jpg'},
{width: 300, height: 400, url: 'http://.........../wp-content/uploads/2015/10/file.jpg'},
]
```

Is there anything like this, or I will have to scan all the upload folder file names with regex?

Comment: The featured image is just the ID of an attachment, all the standard attachment APIs should work on it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't remember a function that will do precisely that, but it is easily achieved with API overall:

1. Retrieve attachment ID with [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/)
2. Retrieve available sizes with [`get_intermediate_image_sizes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_intermediate_image_sizes/)
3. For each size use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), which gives precisely data you need (URL and dimensions).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! :) This is my first time developing with WP and the API and the terminology is a bit frightening. :)

Comment: is there any way to retrieve the current post's generated featured image size, width and height.
  For example if the the featured image set is of size 540 x 400, although it should be of 550 x 550.
   How to retrieve the  current post's featured image size to store $width = 540 & $height = 400 in the current example.

Comment: @Nimesh `wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id)` will get you what you need.

Answer (score 9):

After you get it's ID ( [**get_post_thumbnail_id($YOUR_POST_ID)**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/) ) you need to know the uploads base url and the attachment meta data.

**Uploads base url** can be found in an array returned by [**wp_upload_dir()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/).

**Attachment meta data** can be retrieved by [**wp_get_attachment_metadata()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/).

Here is a handy function I wrote that prepares the url data for **any image attachment, not just featured**.

```
function prepareImageData( $attachment_id ){
  $uploads_baseurl = wp_upload_dir()['baseurl'];

  $prepared = [];
  $data = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_id);
  $prepared = [
    'mime_type' => get_post_mime_type($attachment_id),
    'url' => $uploads_baseurl.'/'.$data['file'],
    'sizes' => [],
  ];

  foreach( $data['sizes'] as $size => $sizeInfo ){
    $prepared['sizes'][$size] = [
      'url' => $uploads_baseurl.'/'.$sizeInfo['file'],
    ];
  }

  return $prepared;
}
```

Comment: excellent! You might also lik to add $dir = pathinfo( $data['file'] )['dirname']; to use as: 'url' => $uploads_baseurl.'/'.$dir.'/'.$sizeInfo['file'],     as they might miss the year/month directories

Answer (score 1):

To get image according to size you can use wordpres pre-defined function that is `the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr )`.

you can use predefined media sizes.

```
the_post_thumbnail();                 

the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)

the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );
```

This might help you.

Comment: The point of the question is that the OP was looking to find the names of all available image sizes including any additional sizes created by the theme &/or plugins.